# How to extend access token with the new iOS SDK 3?

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

Using the new iOS SDK 3.0, how do you extend access tokens? Is this still necessary?

Comment: In what scenario is iOS SDK 3.0 new? You do still need to use access tokens for pretty much everything.

Answer (score 2):

The Facebook SDK handles it itself.

You can reach it any time like so:

```
NSString *accessToken = [FBSession activeSession].accessToken;
```

This will return the accessToken or a nil if no token is set. You can even define a token caching ruleset on the session. Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you use FBSession it handles that internally.